# Want to show pause icon when video set to pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I want to show pause icon when the movie is paused . currently its show only the play icon . I don't know how to do it with javascript help!

My HTML:

```
    <video id="video" height="100%" width="100%" autoplay muted>
      <source src="video/google.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <i class="fa fa-play fa-5x" onclick="playPause()"></i>

    <!-- currently its showing <i class="fa fa-play fa-5x"></i> on play pause both -->
    <!-- want to show <i class="fa fa-pause fa-5x"></i>  on pause -->
```

My js:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video");
 function playPause() { 
  if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
  else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
 }
```

As you can see in this image

[image: as you can see in this image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this at the moment, but assuming your function works, I'd suggest toggling the `fa-play` class-name with the `fa-pause` class-name, which is a simple amendment to your current function:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video");

function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) {
        myVideo.play();

        // removes the 'fa-pause' class from
        // the element:
        myVideo.classList.remove('fa-pause');

        // adds the 'fa-play' class to
        // the element:
        myVideo.classList.add('fa-play');
    }
    else {
        myVideo.pause();
        myVideo.play();
        myVideo.classList.remove('fa-play');
        myVideo.classList.add('fa-pause');
    }
}
```

References:

- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a Glyph Pause Icon for yourself and make it display: block or none depending on your purpose.

You can make one for free on Icomoon